# provide integration for ajax/javascript modal view on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, modal-dialog

I am trying to generate javascript code that can be provided to website owners for them to integrate into their HTML. This code would display a button somewhere on their page which opens up a feedback form in a modal view type overlap on their website.

I realize there are a few plugins for ruby online that go with jQuery to create the modal view on a website but how would I create an integration script like shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uvOptions = {};
   (function() {
       var uv = document.createElement('script'); 
       uv.type = 'text/javascript'; 
       uv.async = true;
       uv.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'widget.uservoice.com/KwRuyHwCUkk17M8jW64HDA.js';

       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I am specifically looking for a gem or a plugin for rails 3 that would make the job easier. If none are available, how hard is it to implement this in rails?

Appreciate any help